# Why is babel not loaded with ngerman option when combined with the igo package?

Tags: babel, languages, date

I am using the `igo` package for developing a little book about problems in the GO game. The strange thing is, that the `igo.sty` file prevents the correct display of the date or the contents name. Instead, it is always the english version. The problem is the `repeat.tex` file, which is called by the style file. I can't see what the reason is, so I ask for help.

Using `babel` I can manually rename e.g. Contents to Inhaltsverzeichnis, but it would be preferred if the `ngerman` option was taken into account.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{igo}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \date{\today}
    \title{Problem}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Abschnitt 1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably using the alternative package `psgo` might be an option for you. At least it does not seem to interfere with `babel`'s `ngerman` in your MWE.

Comment: `repeat.tex` redefines `\repeat`, which is also defined in the standard LaTeX kernel. This redefinition of a kernel command is unexpected and seems to cause issues for `babel`.

Comment: You could try something like `\let\realrepeat\repeat \usepackage{igo} \let\repeat\realrepeat` to restore the proper definition of `\repeat` after loading `igo`, but if code from `igo` needs the incompatible definition of `\repeat` you are out of luck.

Comment: Indeed, the suggestion \let.. etc is not working since igo is using it. OK, now I understand the problem and I can live with it (just redefining).